# Post a message with special characters on Facebook through Temboo

Tags: android, character-encoding, temboo

In my Android app I use the Temboo library to post on user's Facebook wall. Everything is OK except when the message contains non-ASCII characters. For example, if I try to publish the String "Oído", I get on Facebook: "O�do". I suppose I would need to set the charset for the Temboo library (if UTF-8 is not the default charset), but I find nothing on the documentation or I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at Temboo. We made some updates based on your question so encoding should work fine for you now. Please try again and let me know if you're still seeing the issue.

If you ever want to ask us questions directly, the best approach is to contact us via email:

support@temboo.com

We're always available and happy to help.